# Get element position relative to page bottom

Tags: javascript

I use this function to get the y-coordinate of an element relative to the page:

```
function getY(oElement)
{
  var curtop = 0;
  if (oElement.offsetParent) 
  {
    while (oElement.offsetParent) 
    {
      curtop += oElement.offsetTop;
      oElement = oElement.offsetParent;
    }
  }
  else if (oElement.y)
  {
    curtop += oElement.y;
  }

  return curtop;
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing but get the position relative to the bottom instead of the top, there doesn't seem to be something like 'offsetBottom'.

How can I do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compare it to the height of the body/document itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I'll do this eventually if there's no other way. But isn't it possible to get the position relative to the bottom? Even just out of curiosity.

Comment: Could work but I'm not sure as the browser does not know the size of a document until it is fully rendered. Also, I'm not sure if this value would change hiding / showing elements dynamically.

Comment: @Waleed - Getting that value is pretty trivial. It's just a matter of subtracting the offset from the document height.

Comment: @Edmundo You're absolutely right. The value would have to be figured late in the flow, after the rendering has completed.